# Macro with run time argument-change giving wrong ans in cpp

Tags: c++

Hi I have a cpp code for macro like this. But somehow when i change the argument in run time it behaves mystriously. Can't find the reason for this. In constant value it is ok.

```
#include<iostream>
#define prod(a,b) a*b
using namespace std;

int  main()
{
    int x=3,y=4;
    cout<<prod(x+2,y-1)<<endl;
}
```

I am geting 10 for this. But shouldn't it give me the return value 15? Thank your for the advance help.

Comment: Depends, do you want the answer to `x + 2 * y - 1` or `(x + 2) * (y - 1)`? Macros are not functions, they are text replacement.

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you very much. @RetiredNinja

Comment: Also note that in C++ the use of macros is not recommended and that constexpr are preferred. 
Visual studio even has a refactor option for this : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/convert-macros-to-constexpr/. Just right click your macro, chose refactor options and convert to constexpr. (And yes there are cases only macros will work, but that's usually only when you need text replacement in code)